# Regular expression - no underscore as the last character

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

I need help writing a regular expression to meet the following requirements:

- start with a letter
- end with a letter or digit
- have as interior characters only letters, digits, underscore and hyphen

The following expression works well with the exception that it allows underscore as the last character. It should only allow a letter or a digit for the last character:

```
    ^[A-Za-z][\w-]*\w$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use a Character Class

You can use a [POSIX character class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_character_classes) for this. In particular, you could use the alphanumeric class, which is shorthand for `[A-Za-z0-9]`. For example:

```
^[A-Za-z][\w-]*[[:alnum:]]$
```

Comment: Why then not also `[[:alpha:]]` instead of `[A-Za-z]` and `[[:word:]-]` instead of `[\w-]` ..? :)

Comment: @Ωmega 1. The `[:word:]` character class is non-standard; specifically, it's not supported in TCL 8.5, although the shorthand `\w` is. 2. There are lots of ways to rewrite the OPs expression, but they don't necessarily answer his question about how to match the *end* of his expression. 3. There's no real reason in this example not to substitute `[A-Za-z]` with `[:alpha:] ` if you want; locale may be an issue with POSIX classes, but it rarely makes a difference to the regex engine.

Comment: CodeGnome, I was just "playing" with classes, as they are very rarely used.

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways of doing what you're asking is to use a negative lookahead constraint:

```
^[A-Za-z][\w-]*(?!_)\w$
```

The other way is to write out the character class you want (Tcl defines `\w` to be `[[:alnum:]_]`, i.e., the `alnum` class *plus* underscore):

```
^[A-Za-z][\w-]*[[:alnum:]]$
```

These accept *exactly* equivalent strings. Which is better? Well, the only real way to be sure is to test (these timings are on my elderly laptop with an older Tcl version; look at the *relative* timings, not the absolute ones):

```
% set a "abc123abc123abc123_123"
abc123abc123abc123_123
% set b "abc123abc123abc123123_"
abc123abc123abc123123_
% regexp {^[A-Za-z][\w-]*(?!_)\w$} $a
1
% regexp {^[A-Za-z][\w-]*(?!_)\w$} $b
0
% time {regexp {^[A-Za-z][\w-]*(?!_)\w$} $a} 1000
21.207069999999998 microseconds per iteration
% time {regexp {^[A-Za-z][\w-]*(?!_)\w$} $b} 1000
20.577612000000002 microseconds per iteration
% regexp {^[A-Za-z][\w-]*[[:alnum:]]$} $a
1
% regexp {^[A-Za-z][\w-]*[[:alnum:]]$} $b
0
% time {regexp {^[A-Za-z][\w-]*[[:alnum:]]$} $a} 1000
4.0455700000000006 microseconds per iteration
% time {regexp {^[A-Za-z][\w-]*[[:alnum:]]$} $b} 1000
3.510597 microseconds per iteration
```

That looks pretty conclusive to me: don't use lookahead constraints when you can write the class you really want. (Looks like there's potential for future optimization in the RE engine too...)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `^[a-zA-Z][-\w]*[a-zA-Z\d]$` or `^[a-zA-Z][-\w]*[^\W_]$`

Answer (score -1):

```
^[a-z][a-z0-9_\-]+[a-z0-9]$(?i)
```

Comment: I believe there is no `/i` in **tcl**, but `(?i)`.

Comment: Wrong again... Mode modifiers **must appear at the start** of the regex (http://www.regular-expressions.info/tcl.html). Also, there is no need to escape `-` when it is first or last inside of `[...]`. Additionaly, `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is `\w`, so you can short that one, as well as `[0-9]` is `\d`.